# HttpWebResponse output stream doesn't close

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, stream

I'm writing custom `ActionFilterAttribute` and trying to write some data directly into output stream in ASP.NET MVC 3. The data that i'm writing is all that i need to be in response, but after writing there is a extra data after my data - rendered view. I'm trying to close `OutputStream`, but it still stay accesible for writing. How can I close this stream for writing or ignore following HTML rendering?

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
    var acceptTypes = request.AcceptTypes ?? new string[] {};
    var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

    if (acceptTypes.Contains("application/json"))
    {
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Serializer.Serialize(data, response.ContentType, response.OutputStream);
    }
    else if (acceptTypes.Contains("text/xml"))
    {
        response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        Serializer.Serialize(data, response.ContentType, response.OutputStream);
    }
    response.OutputStream.Close();
}
```

**UPD**
For example my data is `{"Total": 42, "Now": 9000}`
And my view is like this

```
<div>
    <span>The data that shouldn't be here</span>
</div>
```

In response i get

```
{"Total": 42, "Now": 9000}
<div>
    <span>The data that shouldn't be here</span>
</div>
```

and it's not valid JSON, as you can see. My aim is to send only JSON or XML

Comment: Try closing the response not the OutputStream

Comment: @DenisPostu when I close response, request can't be completed

Comment: Perhaps you can describe what you're trying to accomplish and what specifically you're getting in the response which is unwanted?

Comment: Okay, you're trying to send a JSON response. Is there a reason that you can't simply return a `JsonResult` from an action?

Comment: @ProgrammingHero project can be extended and I need a custom Action filter, because if there will be some modules with similar actions new programmers on project will use Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V and it smells bad. If I have action filter, it will be used everywhere

Comment: I don't think what you want to do can be achieved by the MVC framework the way you're going about it. Trying to write directly to a stream is going against what the framework is trying to achieve. If you can express what you're trying to achieve, we can probably suggest solutions that work around the problem.

Comment: @ProgrammingHero thanks a lot, but I've already found solution by myself

Comment: I've noticed calling 'Close' or 'Dispose' on HttpWebResponse (or it's underlying ConnectStream) does nothing (or rather it blocks until the entire stream is sent by the server). It's better to call 'Abort' on the HttpWebRequest (that's "REQUEST" not response) which will actually kill the stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After big amount of efforts I found out decision that suits my requirements. It was on the top of the problem. All that I need is to flush response before closing it. But in this case `Content-Length` HTTP header is missed and content's length is written right into response body. So we need just to set this header manually before flushing response.

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
    var acceptTypes = request.AcceptTypes ?? new string[] {};
    var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

    if (acceptTypes.Contains("application/json"))
    {
        WriteToResponse(filterContext, data, response, "application/json");
    }
    else if (acceptTypes.Contains("text/xml"))
    {
        WriteToResponse(filterContext, data, response, "text/xml");
    }
}

private void WriteToResponse(ActionExecutedContext filterContext, object data, HttpResponseBase response, String contentType)
{
    response.ClearContent();
        response.ContentType = contentType;
        var length = Serializer.Serialize(data, response.ContentType, response.OutputStream);
        response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());
        response.Flush();
        response.Close();
}
```

Stream is written into it by `Serializer.Serialize` and this method also returns length of content written in output stream.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET pipeline manages the lifecycle of the response object. If you were to abruptly close the stream or end the response, the components downstream will fail when they attempt to write.

If you want to force the system to end the response, you should call [`HttpApplication.CompleteRequest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx). It will bypass the rest of the events in the ASP.NET pipeline, so it's not without potentially unwanted side-effects, but it is the recommended approach.

More information can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/05/25/response-end-response-close-and-how-customer-feedback-helps-us-improve-msdn-documentation.aspx).

Comment: @Programming_Hero thanks a lot, but it's not exactly what i need. It just keep doing it's usual actions in pipeline and i get the same result